# SoapCoreOptions.Binding is now obsolete

Tags: c#, soapcore

I just updated SoapCore to version 1.1.0.22 and the project to .net 6, and i am getting a warning saying that the property Biding of SoapCoreOptions is obsolete.

The problem is: there is no clue on the property documentation of what i should use instead, and i could not find any documentation.

I need to set the binding becouse i need to change the "MaxReceivedMessageSize" and "ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength", this is a port of an old project that use xml for some relative big data transfer.

What is now the "new" way of setting these values?

My Code:

```cs
//builder is IApplicationBuilder
builder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<IMyService>(options =>
                {
                    options.Path = "URL.asmx";                    
                    options.Binding = AumentarTamanhoString(Lint_TamanhoMaximoRequisicao);
                    options.CaseInsensitivePath = true;

                });

                endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<IMyService2>(options =>
                {
                    options.Path = "URL2.asmx";
                    options.Binding = AumentarTamanhoString(Lint_TamanhoMaximoRequisicao);
                    options.CaseInsensitivePath = true;

                });
            });

            
            static BasicHttpBinding AumentarTamanhoString(int Pint_TamanhoMaximoRequisicao)
            {
                BasicHttpBinding Lobj_Retorno = new()
                {
                    MaxReceivedMessageSize = (long)Pint_TamanhoMaximoRequisicao,                                        
                };
                Lobj_Retorno.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Pint_TamanhoMaximoRequisicao;
                return Lobj_Retorno;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Binding, BufferLimit and MaxStringContentLength are buried a bit. Would you mind providing your code? If you are setting up your SoapEndpoint using the IApplicationBuilder in Startup.cs Configure. Something like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    /// <param name="env"></param>
    /// <param name="loggerFactory"></param>
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {            
        app.UseSoapEndpoint<IMyService>(soap =>
        {
            soap.Binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
            soap.Path = "/Service.svc";
            soap.SoapSerializer = SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer;
            soap.BufferLimit = int.MaxValue;
            soap.UseBasicAuthentication = true;
            foreach(var encoder in soap.EncoderOptions)
            {
                encoder.BindingName = "Basic";
                encoder.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
            }
        });                                        }
```

Comment: added code in the main post. but i use just like this. The code seens to work, no problem so far. Just the warning that worries me.

Comment: Awesome. If it suits you please mark it as Accepted. I am soooo close to 5k I can taste it.

Comment: Sorry, i think i was misunderstood. That is the way i was using and it was working, i get the warning the same way. The objective of the post is to know why do i get the warning? and if the component says that this way of doing is obsolete it should provide an alternative way to do it, the way that is now the "correct way"

Comment: Gotcha. If I get sometime I will take another look at my code and see if there is a more modern way to handle the deprecated properties.